# favicon.ico throwing 404 TemplateLoader exception

Tags: error-message, 404

This is my first Craft site, I inherited it. I've manually set a link tag to my favicon in my templates/_layouts/_header.twig file:

Everything else in that /dist/img folder renders fine - .png, .jpg, .gif. Everything inside the other /dist subdirs renders fine - /css, /js, /pdf... What am I missing? Going directly to the favicon.ico url, I get a blank page with this:

"Unable to find the template â€œ_layoutâ€."

I do not understand the routing - but that feels like a red herring here anyway. I don't have any routes set up in the cms, and everything else in the /dist directory renders fine when I link directly to it. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: can you share an example of a working link and the non working one so we can play spot the difference

Comment: Yes, thanks:http://hopscotchdesignfest.com/dist/img/r4u.png (working) | http://hopscotchdesignfest.com/dist/img/favicon.ico (no dice)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can open a .ico file with the browser directly, that's why the request 404s.

There's two ways to make it do its thing:

- simply place it in the web root, e.g. public/favicon.ico
- use this link tag in your document head: `<link rel="icon" href="{{ url('dist/img/favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">`